# mvc5 form validation update failed

Tags: c#, validation, passwords, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been working on a projectbased on mvc5.
I applied a form validation on my Model class. The "compare" condition is applied User_password and User_Password_Confirm. It works perfectly on insertion. But when I have to update the information of same client bt not password, in this case my MoldeStat.Valid is "false" because I think it is because of "compare" condition on password.

Can someone tell me how Can i solve this issue?
I am facing a problem with "update".

Thank you for your help in advance

my Model class

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string User_Password { get; set; }


    [Compare("User_Password")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string User_Password_Confirm { get; set; }enter code here
```

My controller class

```
   [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit2([Bind(Include = "User_Id,User_Nom,User_Prenom,User_Email,User_Telephone,User_Role,User_Password,User_Password_Confirm,UserCreationDate,User_Status")] User user)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            //db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            //db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.User_Status = new SelectList(db.Account_Status, "Account_Status_ID",    "Account_Status_Nom", user.User_Status);
        ViewBag.User_Role = new SelectList(db.Role, "Role_Id", "Role_Name", user.User_Role);
        return View("edit");
    }
```

View of insert (just password section). Here I tried to set value of User_Password_confirm = User_password but it failed :(

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User_Password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User_Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User_Password)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User_Password_Confirm, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User_Password_Confirm, new { @Value = Model.User_Password })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User_Password_Confirm)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: first thing you can do is ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Aggregate(String.Empty, (current, error) => current + (error.ErrorMessage + "\n"));
To display all your errors in model :)

Comment: I think error is clear. See at the time of "Isnert" I have two fields "password" and "confirm password" (Confirm password is not in from database table). So my model can compare the added value in both fields. But at the time of update, I don't show password. SO by default the value of "confirm password" is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, i suggest you to create two different models : UserCreateModel and UserUpdateModel for example.

Then your code will include some security breach.
if i'm user Id 275, i can change the userId in the form (even if it's hidden), this way i'm gonna be able to change email, password, firstname, lastname of any user.

What you need to do is get the Id of the logged user and change only the data that has been changed.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var userfromDb = db.Users.Find(loggedUser.EmployeeId);
        userfromDb .Email = user.Email;//etc...
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: ya i guess that is the only possibility. I just didnt want to create a seconde model. OR i think i should remove [compare] and [required] validation from password in model class and chek it at the time of update . for exemple : if((ModelState.IsValid) && password == conformPassword){action}. What do you say??

Comment: you can do that, not optimal. Still you will have to change db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified; for security reasons.
I still recommend you to have two models ^^
It doesn't take that much time to have two models (if you are motivated you can even use some heritage for the common part of the models) and it's really a better usage than hardcoding.

Answer (score 0):

You may easily see a summary of all model validation errors by inserting a

```
@Html.ValidationSummary
```

on your view.

Comment: ya i know that. but problem is  when i update the content of table. Actualy confirm_password is just a attribute created by me in model its nt from database.

It works perfectly when I insert data into table but when i update the same data there i face an error because automaticaly the value of confirm password is null. so automatily when Modelstate verify the confirm action it goes false :( hope it is litl bit clear now